# What could be the described method for treating time-outs in algorithm benchmarks

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, censoring

As a computer scientist, you often face the problem to empirically analyse the improvements in run time of some algorithm.

I stumbled over the following text in a paper:

> These run times are averages over 10 runs per benchmark, and account
> for time-outs using maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) [cite]. With
> 90% confidence level, 71% of those averages are accurate to within
> 25%.

The cite is simply a book on statistics "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis, Rice" without page numbers :(

### To explain the setting

Suppose you have a set of algorithms $A$. Every algorithm is applicable to every benchmark problem in your problem set $P$. This gives $|A||P|$ possible configurations. For randomized algorithms, you repeat each configuration $n$ times. This makes a total of $n|A||P|$ experiments.

For each experiment, you measure the time it takes the algorithm to calculate the solution. But for practical reasons, you set a time-out $t_{max}$. So you end up with a set of run-times with na values meaning "larger than $t_{max}$".

The cite is from a caption plotting number of solved instances over time. So I assume they calculated some kind of "average value" for each algorithm/problem combination (over 10 different random seeds), accounting for the time-outs.

Comment: Some clarification is needed here because the data structure is difficult to understand. What are these "time outs"? What is happening in the process during these "time outs"? It sounds like they may be random non-negative noise added to the runtimes but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Macro I've added a bit.

Comment: Your data are *censored*.

Comment: @cardinal Yes, that's what I've got from reading the wiki-page on survival analysis. They're right-censored.

Comment: @ziggy: Right! (Pun!) ;-)